ansible-playbook + how to ignore tasks that already performed in general pb.yml
we are using ansible in order to install our application and configuration on linux machines
here is example of general.pb.yml
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# java apps installtion
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
- import_playbook: /deployment/application/stage1.pb.yml
- import_playbook: /deployment/application/stage2.pb.yml
- import_playbook: /deployment/application/stage3.pb.yml
- import_playbook: /deployment/application/stage4.pb.yml
- import_playbook: /deployment/application/stage5.pb.yml
- import_playbook: /deployment/application/stage6.pb.yml
- import_playbook: /deployment/application/stage7.pb.yml
- import_playbook: /deployment/application/stage8.pb.yml
- import_playbook: /deployment/application/stage9.pb.yml
- import_playbook: /deployment/application/stage10.pb.yml
- import_playbook: /deployment/application/stage11.pb.yml

.
.
.
.
the thing is when we run pb.yml again and again on 2 time or 3 time , its means ansible spending time on the tasks that already performed
I will give example
lets say we run ansible-playbook general.pb.yml and we want to perform only the task - /deployment/application/stage8.pb.yml that not performed correctly on previous time
in that case ansible will  verify all stages from stage1.pb.yml until stage7.pb.yml , and will spend time like 10 min until ansible start with  /deployment/application/stage8.pb.yml
what we did as worker around we comment the lines as following
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# java apps installtion
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#- import_playbook: /deployment/application/stage1.pb.yml
#- import_playbook: /deployment/application/stage3.pb.yml
#- import_playbook: /deployment/application/stage4.pb.yml
#- import_playbook: /deployment/application/stage5.pb.yml
#- import_playbook: /deployment/application/stage6.pb.yml
#- import_playbook: /deployment/application/stage7.pb.yml
- import_playbook: /deployment/application/stage8.pb.yml
- import_playbook: /deployment/application/stage9.pb.yml
- import_playbook: /deployment/application/stage10.pb.yml
- import_playbook: /deployment/application/stage11.pb.yml

and the run again the general.pb.yml
but what I am asking is maybe some way that ansible know the tasks that performed and not verified them again , is it possible ?

Q: "Some way that Ansible knows the tasks that were performed and not verify them again, is it possible?"
A: No. It is not possible. Ansible doesn't keep such records. It would be best if you controlled the flow on your own. There are more options described below. You can combine any or all of them:

Import the playbooks conditionally. For example, in the below project

shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── group_vars
│   └── all
│       └── stages.yml
├── hosts
├── init.yml
├── pb.yml
├── stage1.yml
├── stage2.yml
├── stage3.yml
├── stage4.yml
└── stage5.yml

Create the general playbook
shell> cat pb.yml 
- import_playbook: stage1.yml
  when: stage1|d(false)|bool

- import_playbook: stage2.yml
  when: stage2|d(false)|bool

- import_playbook: stage3.yml
  when: stage3|d(false)|bool

- import_playbook: stage4.yml
  when: stage4|d(false)|bool

- import_playbook: stage5.yml
  when: stage5|d(false)|bool



Note: You can generate the playbook
shell> cat init.yml 
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:

    - copy:
        dest: pb.yml
        content: |
          {% for i in range(1,no_of_stages|d(1)|int + 1) %}
          - import_playbook: stage{{ i }}.yml
            when: stage{{ i }}|d(false)|bool

          {% endfor %}

shell> ansible-playbook init.yml -e no_of_stages=5



and the playbooks to test the stages
shell> cat stage1.yml 
- name: stage 1
  hosts: all

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: ansible_play_name

By default, the playbook does nothing. All imports will be skipped. You can declare the defaults on your own. For example,
shell> cat group_vars/all/stages.yml 
stage1: true
stage2: true
stage3: true
stage4: true
stage5: true

Now, by default, all stages will be executed
shell> ansible-playbook -l localhost pb.yml

PLAY [stage 1] ******************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ansible_play_name: stage 1

PLAY [stage 2] ******************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ansible_play_name: stage 2

PLAY [stage 3] ******************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ansible_play_name: stage 3

PLAY [stage 4] ******************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ansible_play_name: stage 4

PLAY [stage 5] ******************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ansible_play_name: stage 5

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

The utilization of this framework is trivial. For example, if you want to disable the first two stages
shell> ansible-playbook -l localhost pb.yml -e stage1=false -e stage2=false



The next option is --start-at-task of ansible-playbook. You can modify the stages to start with a specific first task. For example,

shell> cat stage1.yml
- name: Stage 1
  hosts: all

  tasks:

    - name: Stage 1
      debug:
        var: ansible_play_name



Note: If you don't want to see any action use meta: noop
shell> cat stage1.yml
- name: Stage 1
  hosts: all

  tasks:

    - name: Stage 1
      meta: noop
      
    - debug:
        var: ansible_play_name



List the tasks
shell> ansible-playbook -l localhost pb.yml --list-tasks

playbook: pb.yml

  play #1 (all): Stage 1    TAGS: []
    tasks:
      Stage 1   TAGS: []

  play #2 (all): Stage 2    TAGS: []
    tasks:
      Stage 2   TAGS: []

  play #3 (all): Stage 3    TAGS: []
    tasks:
      Stage 3   TAGS: []

  play #4 (all): Stage 4    TAGS: []
    tasks:
      Stage 4   TAGS: []

  play #5 (all): Stage 5    TAGS: []
    tasks:
      Stage 5   TAGS: []

If you want to disable the first two stages
shell> ansible-playbook -l localhost pb.yml --start-at-task 'Stage 3'

PLAY [Stage 1] ******************************************************************************************************

PLAY [Stage 2] ******************************************************************************************************

PLAY [Stage 3] ******************************************************************************************************

TASK [Stage 3] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ansible_play_name: Stage 3

PLAY [Stage 4] ******************************************************************************************************

TASK [Stage 4] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ansible_play_name: Stage 4

PLAY [Stage 5] ******************************************************************************************************

TASK [Stage 5] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ansible_play_name: Stage 5

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   


The first option is more flexible.


The next option is tags. You can modify the general playbook. For example,

shell> cat pb.yml
- import_playbook: stage1.yml
  tags: stage1

- import_playbook: stage2.yml
  tags: stage2

- import_playbook: stage3.yml
  tags: stage3

- import_playbook: stage4.yml
  tags: stage4

- import_playbook: stage5.yml
  tags: stage5

List the tags
shell> ansible-playbook -l localhost pb.yml --list-tags

playbook: pb.yml

  play #1 (all): Stage 1    TAGS: [stage1]
      TASK TAGS: [stage1]

  play #2 (all): Stage 2    TAGS: [stage2]
      TASK TAGS: [stage2]

  play #3 (all): Stage 3    TAGS: [stage3]
      TASK TAGS: [stage3]

  play #4 (all): Stage 4    TAGS: [stage4]
      TASK TAGS: [stage4]

  play #5 (all): Stage 5    TAGS: [stage5]
      TASK TAGS: [stage5]

If you want to disable the first two stages you can either skip the tags stage1 and stage2
shell> ansible-playbook -l localhost pb3.yml --skip-tags stage1,stage2
  ...

, or select the other tags. Both commands give the same results
shell> ansible-playbook -l localhost pb.yml -t stage3,stage4,stage5

PLAY [Stage 1] ******************************************************************************************************

PLAY [Stage 2] ******************************************************************************************************

PLAY [Stage 3] ******************************************************************************************************

TASK [Stage 3] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ansible_play_name: Stage 3

PLAY [Stage 4] ******************************************************************************************************

TASK [Stage 4] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ansible_play_name: Stage 4

PLAY [Stage 5] ******************************************************************************************************

TASK [Stage 5] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ansible_play_name: Stage 5

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

The complexity of this option is equivalent to the first one.  But, the first option is more flexible. The variability of setting variables is bigger than that of setting the command options.


Notes

Ansible keeps track of failed hosts. See RETRY_FILES_ENABLED. For example, if enabled, the below play

shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: test_01,test_02,test_03

  vars:

    cmd:
      test_01: 'true'
      test_02: 'false'
      test_03: 'true'

  tasks:

    - command: "{{ cmd[inventory_hostname] }}"

will fail
shell>ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [test_01,test_02,test_03] **************************************************************************************

TASK [command] ******************************************************************************************************
fatal: [test_02]: FAILED! => changed=true 
  cmd:
  - 'false'
  delta: '0:00:00.010241'
  end: '2024-05-17 15:17:01.528741'
  msg: non-zero return code
  rc: 1
  start: '2024-05-17 15:17:01.518500'
  stderr: ''
  stderr_lines: <omitted>
  stdout: ''
  stdout_lines: <omitted>
changed: [test_01]
changed: [test_03]
    to retry, use: --limit @/export/scratch/sandbox/tmp1/test-08/pb.retry

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************
test_01                    : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_02                    : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_03                    : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

and will create the file pb.retry with the failed host(s)
shell> cat pb.retry 
test_02

As suggested in the error message, you can use it to limit the play to the failed host(s)
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml --limit @/export/scratch/sandbox/tmp1/test-08/pb.retry




The utility ansible-playbook provides the users with the option --start-at-task. Unfortunately, this option applies to tasks only. The module import_playbook can't be used as a task:


You cannot use this action inside a play.

As a result, import_playbook can't be used in the option --start-at-task because it is not a task. Test it:
shell> ansible-playbook -l localhost pb.yml --list-tasks

playbook: pb.yml

  play #1 (all): stage 1    TAGS: []
    tasks:
      debug TAGS: []

  play #2 (all): stage 2    TAGS: []
    tasks:
      debug TAGS: []

  play #3 (all): stage 3    TAGS: []
    tasks:
      debug TAGS: []

  play #4 (all): stage 4    TAGS: []
    tasks:
      debug TAGS: []

  play #5 (all): stage 5    TAGS: []
    tasks:
      debug TAGS: []

No import_playbook is listed among the tasks. There are the debug tasks inside the imported playbooks only.


Since the OP's example specifically mentions the occasional errors during the playbook execution, I would emphasize the ability to create the .retry files instead of suggesting to control the workflow manually. This basically goes against the infrastructure-as-code/configuration-as-code principles that Ansible is designed to follow.

The question is specifically about "how to ignore tasks ...".  The .retry files would have been emphasized if the question were specifically about "how to ignore hosts ...".


and we want to perform only the task - /deployment/application/stage8.pb.yml that not performed correctly

Small note here - since that playbook failed, you have to run all the subsequent ones, too.
Apart from an ability to use the retry files mentioned by Vladimir Botka in his answer to re-run the playbook only against the failed hosts, Ansible offers a built-in option to run the playbooks starting from a specific task using --start-at-task command line parameter.
EDIT: corrected my answer due to the fact that we can't use --start-at-task with the named imports directly.
An important note here's that it only works on task level, so it can't be used neither with play names nor import_playbook.
Instead, we can use the name of the first task of each playbook's first play so that we can refer to it instead:
# /deployment/application/stage1.pb.yml
---
- name: Stage 1 play 1
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Stage 1
      debug: # could be replaced with `meta: noop` to make it silent
        msg: "I'm just a task from {{ ansible_play_name }}"

Naming the tasks is a recommended practice and could be enforced using ansible-lint.
After that, if your main playbook failed at stage 8, all you have to do is this:
ansible-playbook general.pb.yml --start-at-task 'Stage 8'

Of course, to save time, you can combine these options:
ansible-playbook general.pb.yml \
    --limit @/Users/alexander/IdeaProjects/stackoverflow/78495001/general.pb.retry \
    --start-at-task 'Stage 8'

PS. Now it looks like Vladimir's answer and mine are similar if not the same. At the same time there are some key differences between them. You can inspect the edit history to track why it happened. I believe that any attempts to introduce manual control of the workflow violate the principles of Configuration-as-Code and increase the complexity, thus increasing the possibility of human error - that's why I'm not recommending usage of conditions and tags to solve this problem.

I must admit that the last answer with --start-at-task is really great.
Let's examine another solution to the question by using Ansible tags. We can simply add tags, such as stage1 to stage11, to every playbook.
# general.pb.yml
---
- import_playbook: /deployment/application/stage1.pb.yml
- import_playbook: /deployment/application/stage2.pb.yml
- import_playbook: /deployment/application/stage3.pb.yml
  [...]

# stage1.yml
- name: Stage 1
  hosts: all
  tags: stage1
  tasks:
    # Your tasks go here

Then we can start the main playbook by specifying which stages we want to be performed - by using --tags
ansible-playbook general.pb.yml --tags stage8,stage9,stage10

We can skip certain stages by using the --skip-tags directive:
ansible-playbook general.pb.yml --skip-tags stage1,stage2,stage3

Subsequent tags must be written without spaces, separated with commas. And we need to be sure that our tags are correctly listed and unique.
What do you think?


"and unique" - here's the problem. Tags are typically used on multiple distinct tasks/plays that could be not following each other. And, unlike names, their presence couldn't and shouldn't be enforced. On the other side, AFAIR tags are the only default way to control the flow by setting the environment variables - all the others would require adding some CLI options which would, in turn, require proper validation when running in controlled environments. So yes, tags could be used to solve this, but one needs to ensure that these tags are so unique that they couldn't be used anywhere else.


I wanted to say that the options --start-at-task and --tags along with --skip-tags do not compete with each other but rather complement each other. In certain situations, as in the question, it might be better to use the simple --start-at-task, while in others, using tags might be more appropriate, for example, if you want to skip a specific task, or even specify the order in which tasks should be executed, like task 3, then 5, and later task 1. It is worth noting that you can use multiple tags for a single task. Using tags gives you flexibility to create complex execution scenarios.
